# Can you remove a published property from a delphi component and not cause errors on the forms where the component is used?

Tags: delphi

I have a component that was developed by my company, and would like to remove one of the published properties that is no longer needed and clashes with the way the component works now.

Is there a way to remove the property and not cause property not found errors at runtime or design time when forms that use the component are loaded?
i.e. Is there a way to make Delphi silently drop a component property?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Depending on the property, the easiest would be to leave the property, but mark it as deprecated and just have the Read/Write bits point to a field that's never used.

Alternatively, you can override `DefineProperties` and call `Filer.DefineProperty('PropertyName', ReadProc);` where **PropertyName** is the property you've removed, and **ReadProc** is a function that calls various TReader Read* functions.  This has the advantage that the properties aren't in your interface anymore.

For example, say you've removed this property:

```
property Center: TPoint read FPoint write SetPoint;
```

Here's what you would add to your component:

```
TMyComponent = class...
private
  procedure SkipReadPoint(Reader: TReader);
protected
  procedure DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler); override;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.DefineProperties(Filer: TFiler);
begin
  inherited;
  Filer.DefineProperty('Center', SkipReadPoint, nil, False);
end;

procedure TMyComponent.SkipReadPoint(Reader: TReader);
begin
  Reader.ReadListBegin;
  Reader.ReadInteger;
  Reader.ReadInteger;
  Reader.ReadListEnd;
end;
```

Skipping a simple type like Boolean or Integer is easier, since you can just call `ReadBoolean` or `ReadInteger` without bothering with the ReadList functions.

In our case we had a lot of similar properties across a bunch of classes (for CLX compatibility) so we had global "dummy" functions like this:

```
procedure DummyReadBool(Self: Pointer; Reader: TReader);
begin
  Reader.ReadBoolean;
end;
const
  SkipReadBool: TMethod = (Code: @DummyReadBool; Data: nil);
```

and then the DefineProperty call looks like this:

```
Filer.DefineProperty('PropName', TReaderProc(SkipReadBool), nil, False);
```

That way each class doesn't have to have duplicate Skip* functions.

Comment: @Nice answer, but the poster wanted to permanently remove the property from the component. There's not much point in going through TReader and adding code to the component streaming mechanism in order to avoid it like this when the property is actually going away forever. This could be very useful, though, when having to maintain backward compatibility.

Comment: @Ken: I don't understand your objection.  Amy specifically asked to load a DFM at runtime and have it not fail on a removed property.  Obviously that's a backwards compatibility requirement or she'd have just opened the form once and told it to delete the reference.  I guess I could have just said "No", but that doesn't seem terribly useful.

Comment: not really an objection; that's why I didn't downvote or anything. Just an observation that, if you're *permanently* removing the property, and you don't need backward-compatibility, you don't need to do the extra work. Backward compatibility means you need to retain it in some versions and not in others; I read her post differently. She also mentioned "in the IDE", not just at runtime.

Comment: Accepted because of all the code snippets - really useful!  Thank you

Answer (score 20):

Yes. Just remove the property, then override DefineProperties and process it there. That will satisfy the streaming system by loading the value which you can just throw away. Be sure to do nothing when writing the stream.

Answer (score 6):

You can't "silently" remove it, if it's stored in the .DFM or referenced in code.

If it wasn't referenced in code, and it's stored in text .DFM files, the [JVCL](http://delphi-jedi.org) has a utility called `DFM Cleaner` that will go through the .DFMs and remove the properties for you. Then you can open the forms and recompile your applications safely. It's part of the `JVCL` and is placed in the `$(JVCL)\DevTools` folder during install.

Comment: So I thought, and would have said myself, but Allen's answer says, you can.  Cool eh?

Comment: The JVCL DFM cleaner utility has one super cool use that I can't live without;  Ability to maintain a source code base that I routinely open in various versions of Delphi, and I need to remove stuff added by newer versions of Delphi that will break older versions (ExplicitHeight, and stuff like that, in Forms and Controls).

Comment: That's one reason I know about it. :) It's also easier if you're permanently changing a component; you use it one time on all the .dfm files in all of your projects, and then build them and the source is clean (provided you've already cleaned up references in source code, of course).